# 12 GB Pendrive .... Is it possible?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I just bought a 12 GB Pendrive. When I tested it, It was only 2 GB (Yeah, I just got cheated).

But then I ask: Is it possible to create a 12 GB Pendrive (specially with 1 chip) ?? If noy, why ??

Comment: Where'd you buy this, a friend?

Answer (score 3):

Sure it is. But it's not practical since it would require three 4GB chips instead of one 8GB or 16GB chip.

Comment: But in only 1 chip, is it posssible ?

Comment: I suppose you could have a 16GB chip with only 12GB marked as usable, but there wouldn't be much point.

Comment: @COCACOLA_SAUDE: [They don't make 12GB chips.](http://superuser.com/questions/235030/why-are-ram-size-usually-in-powers-of-2-512-mb-1-2-4-8-gb)

Comment: @Ignacio: Those are RAM chips, and the chosen answer for that question references the tie between memory address sizes and the CPU. That's completely irrelevant for storage devices.

Comment: @Lèse: Except it really isn't. The reason for both is the same.

Comment: @Ignacio: Is that why 12GB microSD cards exist? And if that were the case, how exactly does a 3-bit MLC NAND chip work?

Comment: @Lèse: [Ask Kevin.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zLk7nJdJcc)

Comment: @Ignacio: Did you even watch the video? He basically refutes your point at around the 2min mark. They chop a 48Gb array to get _roughly_ a 16Gb and 32Gb array. It's _roughly_ because you can't get an even 16Gb/32Gb split on a 48Gb array made from 16Kibi (17179869184) cells. Do the math yourself if you don't believe me... No matter how you split an array of 3-bit cells, you're not gonna get a power of two.

Answer (score 0):

They have just adjusted the controller and/or partition to return those values; in some occasnions reformatting gives you the effective limit, in other cases writing past the limit just makes it wrap around from the start again. So, if you would write 3 GB on a 2 GB, you would be overwriting 1 GB of the first 2 GB that you've written.

Long story short:They indeed tampered with it, trust is an important consideration when buying...